# Is it illegal to copy commercial software features into an open source project?

Tags: software, open-source-software

Imagine I work for a company that has a software X, no algorithm in this software is patented.

If I want to create an open source software Z that has similar features as software X by looking into the code of software X and recreating the logic would that be illegal?

Consider that software Z would be created using different technology, different programming language and would not have copy-pasted code from X.

Comment: it's only illegal if there's some reason it would be illegal

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_room_design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question mixes up two different aspects of intellectual property.

From a copyright point of view, it is perfectly legal to reproduce the features of a one piece of software in another. The functionlity of the software is not copyright (although the detailed [look and feel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look_and_feel) of the user interface might be).

However you ask if you, as an employee, can do this by "*looking into the code of software X*". Presumably by doing this learn something of the organisation and algorithms used. Even if you avoid direct copying, you are likely to have learned trade secrets of your employer, and [publishing these](https://my.eng.utah.edu/%7Ecs5060/notes/tradesecrets.pdf) is at least a civil tort in the US, and in some states a crime.